# Why doesn't my custom Android permission work?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, android-permissions

My company develops two Android .apk files -- An app and a background service.  The app and service interact via Intents.  The service defines a new permission, which must be present in an app's manifest in order to use the service

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.mycompany.myservice.MY_PERMISSION"/>
```

This is a legacy app, built around API_10, and still using Eclipse. Everything seems to work fine except the service cannot be invoked (java runtime exception). The reason given for the exception, as shown in LogCat, is that the app doesn't have said permission -- but it's right there in the Manifest.

How can this be? What would cause such weird behavior? Is it perhaps something weird going on with Eclipse? All the other permission seem to work fine, it's this "custom" one.

I've read some places that install order is important, but I installed the service first, then the app, so this shouldn't be an issue.

Thanks.

Comment: What does the `<permission>` element look like?

Comment: <permission
        android:name="com.mycompany.myservice.MY_PERMISSION"
        android:description="@string/permdesc_MYPERM"
        android:label="@string/permlab_MYPERM"
        android:protectionLevel="normal" />

Comment: Could you show the service component declaration from AndroidManifest?

Comment: OK, that seems fine. Is the user being prompted about this permission at install time?

Comment: I'm running from Eclipse, so no user prompting.

Comment: I noticed the following two lines in LogCat when I tried to install via side-load instead of via Eclipse. Perhaps they indicate possible things I can explore?  "05-02 14:32:26.621: W/ActivityManager(198): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///mnt/sdcard/Download/TestBuild.apk" and "Not granting permission com.mycompany.myservice.MY_PERMISSION to package com.mycompany.app (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x8be46)"